# Как преобразовать строку в массив в json со связанными таблицами

Tags: laravel

Есть такой json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name_ru": "Зона 1",
    "properties": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Компания 1",
      "description": "Описание",
      "color": "rgb(74, 144, 226)",
    },
    "geometry": {
      "id": 7,
      "coordinates": "[[[73.159332,49.912499],[73.161736,49.91781],[73.166199,49.912278],[73.159332,49.912499]]]",
    }
  }
]
```

Вот моя модель:

```
class Regions extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'zone_region';

    public function properties() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Companies::class, 'company_id', 'id');
}

    public function geometry() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Geometry::class, 'geometry_id', 'id_zone');
    }
    protected $casts = [
        'coordinates' => 'array',
    ];

}
```

Сейчас поле `coordinates` возвращается в виде текста, как сделать так чтобы оно возвращалось в виде массива
Я понимаю что уже использую преобразование, но я не обращаюсь к объекту `coordinates` 
Вот как выглядит мой контроллер:

```
public function getMarker(Regions $item){
        return $item->with('properties')->with('geometry')->where('id' , '=', $item->id)->get();
    }
```

Как мне сделать так чтобы из связной таблицы мне возвращался `coordinates` как массив, а не как строка?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, проблема была в том что я преобразовывал не ту модель
Нужно было засунуть:

```
protected $casts = [
        'coordinates' => 'array',
    ];
```

В связанную модель `Geometry`